# Прочитать текстовый файл в текстовое поле

Tags: java

Здравствуйте! С Java знаком недавно, пытаюсь создавать простые оконные приложения, застрял на теме открытия файла через filechooser. В частности необходимо открыть текстовый документ и отобразить его содержимое в компонентах работы с текстом, например textPane. Мой код открывает файл, но отображает не все содержимое в textPane, а только последнюю строку. Видимо прочитав одну строку он не переходит в компоненте на новую строку и прочитывает в ту же строку новую строку из файла, хотя по коду вроде все должно работать. Не могу понять как это исправить, подскажите?

```
JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("Открыть");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            fc.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("C:/"));
            fc.setDialogTitle("Блокнотец");
            fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

            if (fc.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                ///
                try {
                    FileReader fr = new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile());
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                    String str;
                    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(str + "\n");
                        textPane.setText(str + "\n");

                    }
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e0) {
                    System.out.println("Файл не найден!");
                }
                ///
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                String text="";
                String str;
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(str + "\n");
                    text+=str;
                }
                textPane.setText(text);
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e0) {
                System.out.println("Файл не найден!");
            }
```

или так

```
try {
                FileReader fr = new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile());
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

                StringBuilder text= new StringBuilder();
                String str;
                while ((str = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(str + "\n");
                    text.append(str);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
                textPane.setText(text.toString());
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e0) {
                System.out.println("Файл не найден!");
            }
```

Он и не должен переходить никуда. setText() изменяет весь текст на тот, который передан в параметре.

Comment: Действительно, попробовал первый способ - все отлично работает! Спасибо большое! Только пришлось добавить  "\n" к str чтобы на новую строку переходить, а то получается непрерывная строка.... в остальном то что нужно. Скажите, а какой из этих способов более подойдет для работы с большими файлами?

Comment: Да, действительно перенос строки пропустил).Лучше использовать StringBuiler, поскольку text+=str будет постоянно создавать новый объект String, что отразится на памяти